# Crash when using Cocos2d

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d

Sorry about the poor question title, it's just that this seems to big for a title. So here's the dirt:

I am making a game (obviously) and I want the enemies to shoot (not necessarily at the player). I want the shoot method to be in the Enemies file, so as not to clutter up my HelloWorldLayer.m file even more. Here's what I'm using right now:

HelloWorldLayer.m

```
-(void)addEnemy:(BigAndStrongEnemy *)enemy {
enemy = nil;
if((arc4random() % 4) == 3) {
    enemy = [BigAndStrongEnemy enemy];
} else {
    enemy = [SmallAndFastEnemy enemy];
}

if(buffDude.position.y > character.position.y || buffDude.position.y < (character.position.y + 10)) {

}

int rand = arc4random() % 320;

if((arc4random() % 2 == 1)) {
    [enemy setPosition:ccp(0,rand)];
}else{
    [enemy setPosition:ccp(480,rand)];
}
[self animateEnemy:enemy];
[self addChild:enemy];
}

-(void)animateEnemy:(BigAndStrongEnemy *)enemy2 {
    float randX = arc4random() % 480;
    float randY = arc4random() % 320;
    int rand = arc4random() % 320;

CGPoint moveToPoint = CGPointMake(randX, (randY - rand));

[enemies addObject:enemy2];

action = [CCSequence actions:
          [CCMoveBy actionWithDuration:1 position:ccpMult(ccpNormalize(ccpSub(moveToPoint, enemy2.position)), 75)],
          [CCMoveBy actionWithDuration:3 position:ccp(buffDude.position.x,buffDude.position.y)],
          nil];

CCCallFuncO *a = [CCCallFuncO actionWithTarget:self selector:(@selector(shoot:)) object:enemy2];
CCSequence *s = [CCSequence actions:action,a, nil];

CCRepeatForever *repeat = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:s];

[enemy2 runAction:repeat];
}
```

And here's the Shoot info from the Enemies class:

Enemies.m:

```
    -(void)shoot:(id)sender {
    self = (BigAndStrongEnemy *)sender;
    [self shoot];
}

-(void)spriteMoveFinished:(id)sender {
    CCSprite *b = (CCSprite *)sender;
    [self removeChild:b cleanup:YES];
}

-(void)shoot {
    self = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"bigAndStrongEnemy.gif"];
    CCSprite *b = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"bullet.gif"];
    b.position = ccp(self.position.x,self.position.y);
    b.tag = 2;
    [self addChild:b];
    [bullets addObject:b];


CGSize winSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];

CGPoint point = CGPointMake((winSize.width - (winSize.width - self.position.x)),0);

[b runAction:[CCSequence actions:
              [CCMoveBy actionWithDuration:0.5 position:point],
              [CCCallFuncN actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(spriteMoveFinished:)],
              nil]];
}
```

Every time the 3 seconds goes by, the app crashes, and goes to the breakpoint in the CCCallFuncO file. I haven't touched it, is the thing. I am completely confused. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: -1 use your debugger

Answer (score 3):

Use the XCode debugger and do a stack track to see the last line of your code where the crash happened. That should give you a clue on what is causing the error

Comment: I've never used the xcode debugger. How do I?

Comment: @ipodfreak0313 why dont you check the xcode help or google tutorial xcode debugger. This is not the right place to teach basic programming skills

Comment: I wrote an Xcode 4 Debugging Crash-Course article: http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2011/10/xcode-4-debugging-crashcourse/

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with "CCCallFunc". It turned out I needed to be using "CCCallFuncN" instead, confusing because they are so similarly named. I would try replacing the line of code it's tripping up on with

```
CCCallFuncN *a = [CCCallFuncN actionWithTarget:self selector:(@selector(shoot:)) object:enemy2];
```

Answer (score 0):

The enemy class has

```
[self addChild]
```

and

```
[self removeChild]
```

that I think make more sense in the Layer class, unless the Enemy class is based on Layer.

Did you try moving the enemy code to the HelloWorldLayer? I know this is not where you want it to be, but it may be simpler to get it to work, then change it from there.

Answer (score -3):

Bingo. The problem exists in `CCCallFunc`, so try `CCCallFuncN` instead. Hope everything goes well.

Comment: What is "the problem"? Why does using `CCCallFuncN` instead of `CCCallFunc` fix it?

Comment: CCCallFunc calls a selector, CCCallFuncN calls a selector with the Node as a parameter. As I understand it, if you just need to run a method, CallFunc is fine, but if you need to run something for *this* element (that just finished moving, say) then you use CallFuncN so you have a reference to that node.